# result: 32 No such object

Tags: ldap, openldap

When I try to run

> ldapsearch -x

I get an error

> result: 32 No such object

I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 5):

- You have specified no host so it assumes localhost.
- You have specified no port, so it assumes 389.
- You have specified no bind DN so it assumes anonymous bind.
- You have specified no filter so it assumes objectclass=* (I think).

Any of those being bad assumptions could cause it to fail. Generally this should return at least the RootDSE of the local LDAP instance on 389.

Comment: He has also specified no base DN.

Comment: You can specify all above information in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`.

Answer (score 3):

It worked after specifying the base DN of my Server. My LDAP Server has multiple schemas. So need to specify the Base DN from where it has to check from.